# GetKeyboardState not working in remote desktop full screen mode

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am using the win api [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to track all keyboard presses across the system.

This works fine however it has funny behaviour with remote desktop.

If the remote desktop is in windows mode this works correctly however if remote desktop is full screen it doesn’t work.

Has anyone had any experience of this or no how to get keystroke in full screen remote desktop?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on what "it doesn't work" means. Note that `GetKeyboardState` returns only local state, not global state, so it doesn't track keyboard presses across the system.

Comment: I mean that it looks like you cant capture keyboard keys from a remote desktop in full screen using them hooks. it probably bypasses them.

Comment: It shouldn't have worked before. `GetKeyboardState` cannot capture state from other thread groups. (In the absence of attachment games, a thread group is basically a single thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Use hooks, you will receive the keystate before any other program and you can even cancel keystrokes.
Use "SetWindowsHookExW" from user32.DLL for wetting up one hook and "UnhookWindowsHookEx" for removing one.
There are many sample codes,try this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: i am using a similar sample code in my application off code project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C I have tried your sample and it also doesn't work for full screen remote desktop.

Comment: Then you have a problem, because your full screen remote desktop is propably using the function "KeyboardHookProc", which is canceling all keystrokes. I would try to use GetAsyncKeyState, if it isnt working, i dont have an idea anymore.